# Как расшифровать этот код?

Tags: кодировка

NzMgMzIgMTA4IDExMSAxMTggMTAxIDMyIDEyMSAxMTEgMTE3IDMyIDk3IDEwOCAxMDggNDYgMTMgMTAgNjYgMTE3IDExNiAzMiAxMjEgMTExIDExNyAzOSAxMTQgMTAxIDMyIDEwMCAxMTEgMTEwIDM5IDExNiAzMiAxMDggMTExIDExOCAxMDEgMzIgMTA5IDEwMSA0NiA0NiA0Ng==

Comment: это же токен/bearer/какой-то уникальный айди/ключ/допуск

Comment: Это base64. После расшифровки получится список кодов latin-1. Из него получится пара строчек на английском. Вроде стихи.

Answer (score 4):

```
import base64

coded = "NzMgMzIgMTA4IDExMSAxMTggMTAxIDMyIDEyMSAxMTEgMTE3IDMyIDk3IDEwOCAxMDggNDYgMTMgMTAgNjYgMTE3IDExNiAzMiAxMjEgMTExIDExNyAzOSAxMTQgMTAxIDMyIDEwMCAxMTEgMTEwIDM5IDExNiAzMiAxMDggMTExIDExOCAxMDEgMzIgMTA5IDEwMSA0NiA0NiA0Ng=="

decoded = base64.b64decode(coded)   # b'73 32 108 111 ... 46 46 46'
numbers = decoded.split()           # [b'73', b'32', b'108', ... b'46', b'46', b'46']

message = "".join(chr(int(number)) for number in numbers)

print(message)
```

---

*Вывод:*

> ```
> I love you all.
> But you're don't love me...
> ```

(Между прочим, второе предложение неправильно по-английски...)

---

*Объяснение:*

1. Сначала был каждый символ текста закодирован для [ASCII таблицы](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) в виде десятичного числа:

   - **I**: `73`
   - **пробел**: `32`
   - **l**: `108`
   - **o**: `111`
   - и т.д.
2. Затем были добавлены пробелы между ними: `73 32 108 111 ...`
3. Наконец был этот текст закодирован кодировкой [Base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64): `NzMgMzIgMTA4IDExMSAx...`

Для расшифровки поступаем обратно...

Comment: Еще вот так можно (при условии что исходный текст в кодировке latin1): `message = bytes(int(number) for number in numbers).decode()`